# Personal Web Servers

Tags: web-hosting, webserver

I'm looking for a Personal web server to host very light traffic meant for home use only.

What is your take on personal web servers that meet some or most of the criteria below?

- Free/Open source
- Runs on Windows and possibly Linux (Ubuntu)
- Very light on resources
- No installation required or standalone file
- Admin console - GUI or Web based
- Supports multiple hosts/port mappings

I have tried Abyss who's standard edition is free but limited to one host only.
I've seen lite speed, haven't tried though
XAAMP is another one I'm considering...

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at [MicroApache](http://microapache.amadis.sytes.net/). Very small, free and open source, no install required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Amahi Home Server?  It runs off of Fedora 12, but a Ubuntu version is coming pretty soon.

[www.amahi.org](http://www.amahi.org/)

Comment: thx, but it doesn't run on windows and ubuntu is also coming soon...

Comment: I said that it a Ubuntu version was coming soon. But you're asking for it to run on Windows, so ya, ok. gotcha.